# Batch file to read ini

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, ini

I am trying to automate editing the `boot.ini` depending on the partition XP loads from.
This is a snippet of the batch I am working on.  One minute it works and the next it fails.
It doesn't always correctly read from the `boot.ini`    Any suggestions ?

```
@echo off
find "multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS" boot.ini | sort /r | date | find "=" > en#er.bat
echo set value=%%5> enter.bat
call en#er.bat
del en?er.bat > nul
echo Value is %value%


if "%value%" NEQ "multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS" goto try2
if "%value%"=="multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS" echo multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="- EMERGENCY SPYWARE SCAN MODE" /SAFEBOOT:NETWORK /SOS /BOOTLOG /NOGUIBOOT >>boot.ini
goto NEXT

:try2
find "multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS" boot.ini | sort /r | date | find "=" > en#er.bat
echo set value=%%5> enter.bat
call en#er.bat
del en?er.bat > nul
echo Value is %value%


if "%value%" NEQ "multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS" goto try3
if "%value%"=="multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS" echo multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="- EMERGENCY SPYWARE SCAN MODE" /SAFEBOOT:NETWORK /SOS /BOOTLOG /NOGUIBOOT >>boot.ini
goto Next

:try3
find "multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS" boot.ini | sort /r | date | find "=" > en#er.bat
echo set value=%%5> enter.bat
call en#er.bat
del en?er.bat > nul
echo Value is %value%

if "%value%"=="multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS" echo echo multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="ECLIPSE COMPUTERS - EMERGENCY SPYWARE SCAN MODE" /SAFEBOOT:NETWORK /SOS /BOOTLOG /NOGUIBOOT >>boot.ini
if "%value%" NEQ "multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS" ECHO Please Edit Boot.ini Manually !!!!!
pause
ECHO multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS="- EMERGENCY SPYWARE SCAN MODE" /SAFEBOOT:NETWORK /SOS 

/BOOTLOG /NOGUIBOOT >>boot.ini
notepad.exe boot.ini

:NEXT

echo This is me being happy...boot.ini
```

Comment: As a longtime sysadmin, I have a couple comments that are not exactly pertinent to your question: (a) this is a little scary to do in NT shell where you can't easily handle errors and double-check the changes, so it could easily make the PCs unbootable, and (b) do you really want the computers connected to the network when in "EMERGENCY SPYWARE SCAN MODE"?

Comment: This is done as part of a clean up routine. It adds a second entry to the boot.ini. The second entry adds safemode w/ networking (labeled emergency scan mode). This gives the customer a slim chance to be able to boot up and run their spyware scanafter being infected . I can successfully append it to the boot.ini but I have to pause the script and check to make sure it went to the rihgt partition number. The customer is not at risk of not booting ...due to the fact it only appends to existing boot.  Customer has to have network access to DL updates.

Comment: Ok , so this code will give me the boot info I need.  Any ideas for to remove everything after the equals mark so I can edit it with my own ?
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect 

@echo off

SET NthLine=5
SET /A NthLine -= 1
CALL :LINEGRAB
GOTO RESTOFFILE

:LINEGRAB
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('MORE /E +%NthLine% boot.ini') DO (
    SET T=%%A
    GOTO:EOF
)

:RESTOFFILE
echo %T%

Comment: SOLVED, I figured it out thanks.

Comment: Please post your solution. Tnx.